# What is the JavaFX equivalent of androids AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, networking, javafx

I currently have to do some network operations for my javaFX program, and this is how im doing it now:

- 1 Thread class
- 1 Interface with callback methods
- 1 Main class Implementing that Interface

I am implementing those inside the Main class and getting updates like onProgress(), onDone() etc.. via the Thread class which has a Interface object inside it..

However in android this task is a lot easier, Just using the AsyncTask which works great.

**There you have**

// Ui thread

- onPreExecute()

// Background Thread

- doInBackground()

// Ui thread

- onProgressUpdate()

// Ui thread

- onPostExecute()

Is there a Class that works this way too, in JavaFX? I need progress updates for a progress bar and I need to know when a task is done without freezing the UI screen.

Comment: Have you read the [API docs for `Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html)?

Comment: @James_D have not, thank you, I have now figured it out.

Comment: check this [answer](https://medium.com/@victorlaertedoliveira/archive-javafx-asynctask-a-easy-way-to-handle-multithreading-in-javafx-26689f3cd8fa)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not an Android programmer, so I cannot verify that this is a direct equivalent, but it sounds as though you are looking for the [`Task` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html).

You can create a `Task` and either use it as a `Runnable` in a background thread, or submit it to an `Executor`. You can bind to, or register a listener with, its [`progressProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#progressProperty--) and you can register handlers via the [`setOnSucceeded`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#setOnSucceeded-javafx.event.EventHandler-), [`setOnFailed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#setOnFailed-javafx.event.EventHandler-) and similar methods.

The `progressProperty` (and other properties) are updated on the FX Application Thread (so it is safe to update the UI in response to changes in their values), and the handlers for the state events (succeeded, failed, etc) are also invoked on the FX Application Thread.

Comment: can you please answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973236/returning-values-from-thread)